# Full name of operators in LLVM

Tags: llvm, instructions

How do I get the whole name of an operator in LLVM?

I'm iterating through blocks, and then, in each of their instructions, I try to get the operator name, but I do only get a part of it. Running the following code:

```
virtual bool runOnBasicBlock(BasicBlock &bb) {
    for (auto it(bb.begin()); it != bb.end(); ++it) {
        errs() << it->getName() << '\t' << *it << '\n';
    }
}
```

I get output lines like:

```
icmp        %cmp = icmp slt i32 %i.0, %argc
icmp        %cmp1 = icmp sgt i32 %call, %max.0
add       %inc = add nsw i32 %i.0, 1
```

I'd like to get `icmp slt`, `icmp sgt`, and `add nsw`, instead of `icmp` and `add`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, `slt`, `sgt` and others for `icmp` are just arguments. You can access them with `getPredicate` (a method of `CmpInst`). Also see the useful function `getPredicateText` in `lib/IR/AsmWriter.cpp`.

For stuff like `nsw`, check out the method `hasNoSignedWrap` and similar methods.

Comment: But then, how do I access these arguments? From the instruction, I mean. I've been trying `it->getOperand(i)->getName()`, but I only get the operands -- and I didn't find any `getArgument(i)`.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer. Isn't there anything a bit more generic, that would allow me to iterate over the instruction, printing the information I get when I print the instruction itself? Or do I have to treat each case -- comparisons, sums, branches, and others?

Comment: @Rubens: you can `dump` the instruction, but if you want to programmatically decompose it to parts you have to accept that instructions are different, and each has a distinct set of attributes, flags, arguments and capabilities. So there's no "generic solve all" approach

Comment: Is there a way to directly access the definition of `getPredicateText`, from *AsmWriter.cpp*? My will is to "rewrite" the `printInstruction` function from *AsmWriter.cpp*, but I need access to most of the (static) functions there defined.

Comment: @Rubens: I don't know if that's possible